# Resolve all classes that annotated with Attribute as IEnumerable<Type> using Autofac

Tags: c#, attributes, autofac

I have 3 classes annotated with Attribute

```cs
[MyAttribute("xyz")]
class Class1
{}
//... other classes annotated with MyAttribute
```

I registered all types

```cs
IContainer container ;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//register all types annotated by MyAttribute
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null);

//other registered classes /services

container = builder.Build();
```

Try to resolve:

```cs
//what this line(s) can be for only class that annotated by attribute
IEnumerable<Type> types =  container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Type>>();
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21837997/3142139) didn't help

How to resolve and get `IEnumerable<Type>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null);
```

Under the covers it's *basically* doing this:

```cs
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null)
foreach(var type in types)
{
  builder.RegisterType(type).AsSelf();
}
```

Let's say you had three types with the attribute: `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, `MyClass3`. That means the registration would *basically* be the same as:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MyClass1>();
builder.RegisterType<MyClass2>();
builder.RegisterType<MyClass3>();
```

At no point in there are you registering the type `Type` with Autofac.

Honestly, I'd recommend against registering super generic base types like `string` or `Type` with Autofac anyway. I'd create a factory that gets the information. That way if I ever need to have two different lists of `Type` then I could separate them easily by using two different factory interfaces.

But let's say you want to do that anyway, you actually have to register `Type` not `MyClass1` or whatever. Autofac doesn't do that sort of thing out of the box. You will have to do it yourself.

I don't have this running through a compiler, but it should be something like...

```cs
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null)
foreach(var type in types)
{
  builder.RegisterInstance(type).As<Type>();
}
```

The idea is that you want the `Type` registered so you can list those things, not that you're trying to instantiate the things you located. You don't want to `RegisterType(type)` because that means, basically, that you want Autofac to be able to *create an instance* of `type`, not *track the list of those types so you can get them later*. This sort of confusion is another great reason to put this behind a factory of your own creation.

Really simply:

```cs
public class TypeFactory
{
  public IEnumerable<Type> Types {get;}
  public TypeFactory(IEnumerable<Type> types)
  {
     this.Types = types;
  }
}
```

Then:

```cs
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null)
var factory = new TypeFactory(types);
builder.RegisterInstance(factory);
```

Then resolve `TypeFactory` instead of trying to resolve directly an `IEnumerable<Type>`.